# JPA интерфейс не принимает сущность в @Querry

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, crud, spring-jpa

Добрый день. В рабочем Spring MVC приложении пытаюсь настроить собственный запрос в интерфейсе, расширяющем CrudRepository JPA, но IDE  не принимает никак запрос. Вот сам запрос:

```
@Query (value = "Select b FROM Books WHERE Books.BOOK_TITLE LIKE ? AND Books.autor LIKE ?", nativeQuery = true) 
List<Books> listAllBooks();
```

В ответ IDE подчеркивает AND и сообщает: number expected, got AND. Как исправить?

Если даже создать простой запрос типа:

```
@Query (value = "Select b.autor FROM Books b", nativeQuery = true)
List<Books> listAllBooks();
```

То IDE подчеркивает Books и не определяет его как сущность.

Само приложение опубликовано на гитхабе: https://github.com/oleggalimov/books

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться и исправить. А главное - как же все-таки правильно создавать такие запросы?

Comment: Возможно это не настроенная сама IDE, у меня тоже подчеркивает все сущности красным, но все работает как по маслу. у Вас только подчеркивает или же и не работает?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать чистый sql : `nativeQuery = true`, вместо hql, попробуйте убрать этот параметр

Comment: Действительно, компилируется без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

1. IDE действительно подчеркивает наименование сущности, но приложение компилируется и работает без проблем. Спасибо @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, @Виктор, @MrFylypenko!
2. Ошибка "...Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters.." связана с тем, что в запросе перед параметрами нет двоеточия.
   Всем добра и плюс к карме! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы можете указать столбцы в кавычках

   ```
   @Query (value = "Select b FROM Books WHERE \"Books.BOOK_TITLE\" LIKE ? AND \"Books.autor\" LIKE ?", nativeQuery = true)
   ```
2. Отключить проверку в настройках IDE

   ```
   Settings -> Incpections -> Jpa issues "Unresolved queries and query parameter" снять галочку
   ```

Comment: Действительно, если приложение компилируется не смотря на подчеркивания, без правки запроса.

Comment: Я переписал запрос:

@Query(value = "select b from Books b where b.autor like concat('%', autor, '%') or b.izdatel like concat('%', izdatel, '%') ")
    List<Books> listAllBooks1(@Param("autor") String name, @Param("izdatel") String izdatel);

Comment: Но при выполнении этого запроса уже получаю ошибку:

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1